# How to get the SYSTIMESTAMP in mongo db

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

in SQL, SYSTIMESTAMP returns the system date.

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

SYSTIMESTAMP
------------------------------------------------------------------
28-MAR-00 12.38.55.538741 PM -08:00
```

The above query return the system date. so my question is how can I get the SYSTIMESTAMP in mongo db.

Comment: You can use `$$NOW` follow this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)

Comment: I suggest you to replace "_in Oracle PL/SQL_, ..."

Comment: `$$NOW` is available only in [Aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html). Otherwise simply use `ISODate()` or `new Date()`